# Javascript change input field name in php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I've got a table inside a form.  The table is only displaying the first row with the form fields.  Then in the next field javascripts executes inserts  another row into the table.  The field is named qty1 for the first row, as soon as the javascripts executes and another row is added the field name should become qty2, etc.

In my form results page it is not pulling through the qty2 input field value, only qty1.  What am I doing wrong.  I am not a javescript expert.

First row:

```
$x = 1;
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="qty' . $x . ' id="qty" size="6"/></td>';
echo '<td><input onfocus="grndTot()" type="text" name="grandTot1" id="grandTot1" size="10" readonly/></td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Then the function to insert the row

```
function grndTot() {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(2);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

cell1.innerHTML = cell1.innerHTML = <?php $x++; echo json_encode("<input type="text" name="qty' . $x . ' id="qty" size="6"/>"); ?>;
cell2.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
}
```

On the results page

```
echo $_POST['qty1'];
echo $_POST['qty2'];
```

Then I am only seeing qty1 results.

Comment: You can't mix javascript and php like that, the php has already finished processing before the javascript starts. You need to do this all in javascript, keeping a counter there and not in php.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of numbering your field names you can make them into arrays. Then for each row of your table you'd have a new array index, e.g.

Row 1:

```
<input type="text" name="qty[]">
```

Row 2:

```
<input type="text" name="qty[]">
```

When PHP gets hold of the `$_POST` data it'll be a multidimensional array. So the two quantity fields will be accessible like this:

```
echo $_POST['qty'][0];
echo $_POST['qty'][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript method to:

```
function grndTot(var totalRows) {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(totalRows);


for(var i=0; i < totalRows; i+2){
var cell1 = row.insertCell(i);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(i+1);
var element = document.createElement("input");
element1.type="text";
element1.name= "qty "+i;
cell[i].appendChild(element1);

cell[i+1].innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
```

}
    }